# Override localization file in WordPress plugin for datepicker with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, localization, datepicker

I am using a WordPress plugin called [HBook](http://codecanyon.net/item/hbook-hotel-booking-system-wordpress-plugin/10622779) which is a searchable availability calendar for hotels. It uses a jquery datepicker. The developer's localization file for the datepicker is making the week start on Monday. My client is in the US and needs the week to start on Sunday. Is there a jquery snippet or something else I could add to my theme to override the "firstDay" in the localization file? I've tried messing around with it but I am not so great with jquery.

I asked the plugin developer if there was a way to do this, but he said there was not. He said I would just have to change the plugin file. I'd rather not do this since I will lose my changes with future releases. He did say he would consider adding this feature to the plugin settings page in a future release, but he had no guess on when this would be.

Here is the plugin's [localization file](http://mauioceanview.juliataylordesign.com/wp-content/plugins/hbook/utils/datepicker-lang/datepicker-en-US.js?ver=1.2.4).

If this is just not possible I would appreciate someone telling me that so I can move on! thanks!

Comment: Here's the page which uses the plugin: http://mauioceanview.juliataylordesign.com/check-availability/

Comment: just un enquene the js file and add your own custom one from your theme fucntions

Comment: Could you put a link to a sample page with the datepicker? Could be the plugin uses a date-picker jquery/js plugin that could be set to week start at Sunday.

Comment: Here is the page that uses the plugin and datepicker: http://mauioceanview.juliataylordesign.com/check-availability/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay), you can initialize the datepicker with the `firstDay` option specified:

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).datepicker({
   firstDay: 0
});
```

If you want to change it after initialization, you can use

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "firstDay", 0 );
```

Here is the code for your *custom.js* file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hb-input-datepicker').on("focus", function() {
        jQuery(this).datepicker( "option", "firstDay", 0 );
    });
});
```

Comment: Changing it after initialization sounds like the thing I need to do, but I don't think I'm doing it right, as it's not working

Here's my js file: http://mauioceanview.juliataylordesign.com/wp-content/themes/mauioceanview/js/custom.js?ver=1.0

Here's where the plugin is used: http://mauioceanview.juliataylordesign.com/check-availability/

Comment: There are two things to consider: 1) Put your code inside `jQuery( document ).ready()` to run it once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. 2) Because you are using Wordpress, you need to enqueue jQuery with `jQuery` instead of `$`. _I have added the code for your custom.js file to my answer._

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code to yours, but it's still not working.

Comment: I have updated the code so that it will be executed after the input field with the datepicker receives focus. Please try it.

Comment: I'm using this and while it is working to adjust the firstDay it also clears out any existing date in the filed and changes the date format. Any idea why?